# How do I update a ViewModel in a view with AJAX?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to update a ViewModel from the view using AJAX without hitting a controller?  I'd like to build a data set to before its submitted to the controller to be saved. Is this possible?  If so, how is it done?

Comment: you have to make another action in controller for it, you cant do without calling action

Comment: What do you mean with 'updating a ViewModel'? Do you mean something different from setting some values in a form before POSTing it to the controller?

Comment: I'd like to update the ViewModel from the view itself before its posted to the controller.  The view needs to build a list which won't be saved to the DB until posted.

Comment: Why would you need to update a View Model? Why can't you just POST the list to the controller?

Comment: The whole form has data on it that needs to be updated as a final single request for approval.  The part of the form that's been giving me headaches is the list of groups the user should belong to.  This could be none or twenty.  Posting the form back and forth doesn't give the visual I want but posting the single list doesn't give me the individual record I need on the backside.  I should also mention I have a DropDownList that contains the possible groups to select from...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes every thing is possible in mvc :)

Example

use jquery ajax call and call your url using @URL.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")

and hit the method

```
public JsonResult ActionName(){
JsonObjectWhatEver value = new JsonObjectWhatEver();
return Json(value,JsonBehaviour.AllowGet);   /// check the name is it JsonBehaviour or some thing simillar
}
```

And now you know how its done :)

Comment: Controller holds your methods which gives you updated data so definitely you have to hit your JsonResult Method